# Is it safe to assume that a webserver will always ignore the fragment identifier (#) of the url?

Tags: url, webserver

Let's say I have the following URL: `http://www.example.com/image.jpg`

I want to add some "metadata" to this URL, namely the width and height of the image, to be used client side. However, this "metadata" should not interfere with the URL itself, meaning the URL should still be perfectly valid. I though of using the fragment identifier (# portion) of the URL like this:

`http://www.example.com/image.jpg#800x600`

On browsers, this shouldn't be a problem since, by default, they don't send the fragment identifier in requests. But when performing requests with cURL, for instance, that might not be the case.

**Q: Is it relatively safe to assume that a webserver will always ignore the hash portion of the URL?**

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put metadata next to the image (or other links) there's probably a better way. If it's used in html then adding data-* attributes to the element is probably more useful.
But strictly answering to your question, browsers, curl or wget do not send the fragment in the request. But if you telnet in and send `GET /#foo` at least apache2 ignores it. Probably there's an RFC about this :)

Comment: Thanks. I've tested with Apache2 and IIS. They seem to ignore the fragment identifier so far.

Comment: Unfortunately we're using a proprietary system that only saves image urls so, the only way to inject "metadata" is through the URL. Or redesign the system altogether =P